# awk script to identify duplicates by column and tag highest version

Tags: unix, sorting, duplicates

Looking for UNIX scripting commands such as awk, sed, or sort to look at this list determine duplicates based on 1st, 2nd, and 3rd columns, then use 4th column to determine which is the highest version.  Then tag it in the last column.

Already did all of my sorting and duplicate removal with the following command:

```
cat orig.txt |sort -t\| -k3 |uniq -u -d > list.uni 
sort -t'|' -k 1,3 -k 4,4n list.uni > list.txt
```

Sample listing of part names we will call list.txt

```
cat list.txt

M86-STD|LIB DRAWING|0186-528013|2| | 
M86-STD|LIB DRAWING|0186-528013|3|B| 
M86-STD|LIB DRAWING|0186-528013|4|C| 
M86-STD|LIB DRAWING|0186-528013|5|D| 
M86_STD|LIB ASSEMBLY|0186-528013|3| | 
M86_STD|LIB ASSEMBLY|0186-528013|4|B| 
M86_STD|LIB ASSEMBLY|0186-528013|5|D|
```

Result would be appear as follows:

```
M86-STD|LIB DRAWING|0186-528013|2| | 
M86-STD|LIB DRAWING|0186-528013|3|B| 
M86-STD|LIB DRAWING|0186-528013|4|C| 
M86-STD|LIB DRAWING|0186-528013|5|D|Highestver
M86_STD|LIB ASSEMBLY|0186-528013|3| | 
M86_STD|LIB ASSEMBLY|0186-528013|4|B| 
M86_STD|LIB ASSEMBLY|0186-528013|5|D|Highestver
```

Thanks

Comment: I hope you approve of my reformatting. use {} on edit tool to keep blocks togehter. You can roll back edits if these aren't appropriate by click on the 'edit' tag near my name and finding the undo tag. Good luck

Comment: Just wondering about your commands, what's the point of the flags given to `uniq`? Wouldn't a simple `uniq` without flags achieve the same result? And how come the results ordered by version in *descending* order, where did you tell `sort` to do so? Shouldn't that be `4,4rn` for reverse order?

Comment: yes, you are correct, I was tinkering with my code, updated it in this question, but did not update the listing.  I updated this to reflect the proper descending order of the listing

Comment: You are also correct in that the uniq statement would work with no flags.  And I removed them from my original code.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F'|' -e '{b=$1"|"$2"|"$3;h="highest version";if(a==b)h="";a=b;print $0 h}'
```

The idea is that `b` contains the three columns identifying the current sequence of rows. `a` has the corresponding value of the previous row. If the two differ, then this is the first row of a set, therefore the highest version.

Comment: Sorry, I never thanked you for this answer.  Works in my case.